# auto_discover_link_tag ignores url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-auto_discovery_link_tag),

```
auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, {controller: "home", action: "public_archives"})`
```

Should return

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="ATOM" href="http://www.currenthost.com/home/public_archives" />
```

but I'm getting just the host without the controller or action.

```
<link href="http://currenhost.com/" rel="alternate" title="ATOM" type="application/atom+xml" />
```

Comment: What are your routes? The generated href depends on your routes.

Comment: https://github.com/elm-city-craftworks/practicing-ruby-web/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Comment: sure that isn't your `root_path`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually using `archives_public_url` or something to that effect. My question is why doesn't hash with controller and action work.

Comment: Wait, @phoet, are you saying that since its my root path, its returning the root path?

Comment: your definition is ambiguous, the `root_path` will take precedence. you need to explicitly use something like `archives_public_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `root_path` is `home#public_archives`, `auto_discovery_link_tag` is behaving as expected.

For example, if you put:

```
auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, {controller: "articles", action: "index"})
```

The output would be:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="ATOM" href="http://www.currenthost.com/articles" />
```

Not

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="ATOM" href="http://www.currenthost.com/articles/index" />
```

because the path for `articles#index` is `/articles`. The href it is returning is the first path in your routes file that matches the listed controller and action. In your case, contoller `home` and action `public_archives` first matches `/`.